# NX and Jest don't find all my tests that end with spec.tsx

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nomachine-nx

Hi I am new with nx and I was kinda confuse with it. I have multiple tests in my projects but for some reason jest doesn't find any of it. They do have the extension spect.tsx and I wanted to know what part of the the code is use to make it able to search the them.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by the Nx Jest preset not including the .tsx extension for modules and ts-jest transformations.
I fixed it by editing `jest.config.js`.

Before:

```js
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset').default;

module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset
};
```

After:

```js
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset').default;

module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'mjs', 'html'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(tsx?|js|html)$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```